# How to use ptrace() to observe process until it exits?

Tags: c, macos, wait, ptrace

I am looking for a `ptrace()` call to observe a process until the process exits.

I have this which compiles with gcc / cc on OSX:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pidx = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("pid = %jd\n", (intmax_t) pidx);
    ptrace(PT_ATTACHEXC, pidx, 0, 0);
    wait(NULL);
}
```

However, even with a valid/existing pid, this program will still exit immediately. I am trying to only exit this program after `pidx` dies.
Is this possible somehow?
Ideally I want something that works on both OSX and Linux.

Comment: Perhaps I should be using `strace` instead of `ptrace`, but I don't have `strace` on my Mac.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58601/113238

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably that the `wait` call returns immediately, because the traced "inferior" process is suspended, you know, waiting for you to debug it.  You're going to need some kind of loop in which you make `ptrace` requests to inspect the child and then resume execution, and then call `wait` again to wait for it to suspend on the next breakpoint or whatever. Unfortunately the debugger API is extremely non-portable; you will have to write most of this program twice, once for OSX and once for Linux.

Comment: yeah I am trying to avoid a loop - trying to get a polling-free implementation...it's hard to figure out how to do that

Comment: in my case, I am not trying to create a debugger - I am just trying to listen to the process - I want the ptrace / dtrace / strace command to exit when the pid exits.

Comment: I need you to be more specific about what you mean by "listen to the process".  Presumably you want to do something that is more than just a normal wait for the process to complete?  Whatever that thing is, that's what goes in the body of the ptrace/wait loop.